# How to treat encrypted data?

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption

Let's take an example of an algorithm that calculates the average point scores of a specific class. I need to keep students privacy (students can't know the average point scores of each other, and even the algorithm can't ). Here are steps :

1. ***Student sends his average point scores `encrypted` to the algorithm.***
2. ***The algorithm treats each student's encrypted data (`without decrypting it`)***.
3. ***Finally, the algorithm returns the average point scores of the whole class.***

**Note:** We can have communications between students and the algorithm. In other words, the algorithm and the student can send each other data (as well as the encrypted average point scores ) but students privacy must be always kept.

**So here come my questions:**

- ***Is it possible to implement this algorithm according to the constraints given above?***
- ***If no , Can anyone suggest generic manner to secure students data?***

Comment: You will have to decrypt the data before processing them. Why do you want to encrypt the data in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to decrypt the data, I don't want to know the point scores of each student, so I want to use these encrypted data in my algorithm without decrypting them

Comment: Multi-party computation and fully homomorphic encryption are the obvious choices, but I somehow doubt that such a protocol can be devised. You have to ask yourself, who knows the private key and can that somebody sniff the traffic to decrypt every encrypted score.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, sending encrypted data to the server can perfectly keep data secured and private. Because even the server won't be able to decrypt  the data which is pretty good to increase app security.

Comment: You could either decrypt just the scores, or send the scores in the clear.  Other data, such as the student's name can be encrypted: "Name ajeotyushrn Score: 42"  That way you can calculate an average not associated with the names.

Comment: If you encrypt the scores there is no way you can process them in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Rossum i need to send the scores encrypted.

Comment: @Lasse can you point to the source of this information

Comment: The whole point of encryption is to render data uninterpretable until decrypted. How can you calculate the average of numbers you don't know what are?

Comment: Have each message in two parts.  Part 1 is the encrypted non-score data, possibly encrypted with a key that you do not know.  Part 2 is the score data, encrypted with a key that you do know.  Decrypt part 2 only for your calculations.  This will need a bit more processing at the sending end.